# Adding symbol Image to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I am attempting to work through "Getting to know Web GIS" by Pinu Fu, and I think it may be out of date with the current arcgis online. I am attempting to add an image from a URL (http://esrimapbook.esri.com/GTKwebgis/chapter2/blue_down.gif) and the channge symbol window (change style>counts and amounts (color), Options>Symbols) Yet unfortunatly it does not have an add an image option (see below): [image]

am I looking in the wrong place?

No blogs I have found seem to help, how do you add an image to the symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the option 'Counts and amounts (color)' [Image 1] then you'll be unable to select an image as a symbol as the symbol's colour is a variable in this style type and AGOL does not have the capability to adjust the colour of an uploaded image. If you select 'Counts and amounts (size)' you will be able to upload an image as your symbol [Image 2], but depending on the data you're trying to map this might not be an option.

[image: Image 1: symbolise by size]

[image: Image 2: by symbolise colour]